# A contractible space with an equivalence relation is not contractible

Tags: algebraic-topology

How am I going to exhibit a contractible space X together with an equivalence relation ~ such that X/~ is not contractible?

What I have in mind is that I will have to find for a contractible space and when I add an equivalence class in it, the result will either be a circle or a sphere. But I don't know if this is possible and I don't know what contractible space would that be.

Can anyone help me on how to figure this out? Also, on how will I present my solution?

Comment: That's easy, just identify endpoints of a closed interval. You'll get a circle. Equivalently consider the map $x\mapsto e^{2\pi i x}$ for $x\in [0, 1]$ and take the induced quotient on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Identiy the end points of $[0,1]$?

Comment: Is it enough to have a close interval as my contractible space? 

Sorry. I'm really a beginner here in this field. I really need a detailed info. Thank you!

Comment: @She'sFine You've been asked to provide an example so yes, it's sufficient to use a closed interval as your contractible space. Simple examples are often the best.

Comment: I think i already got it. Thank you!